# In a bash script, how may I use "tr -d" to delete a user entered char?

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":r" opt; do
    case $opt in
    r)
    [ -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
    read $userinp
    cat $input | tr -d "$userinp"
    ;;
    esac
done
```

That is my code. Essentially I'm trying to either parse a file *or* a string and have the user choose a character to delete from the text or string.

The call would be something like:

```
/stripchars -r 'd' test > out
```

This would remove all instances of `d` from the `test` file and place the new string or text in `out`. At the moment I'm just getting empty outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The character (or set, or range) to delete is given by the `-r` flags's argument, so there's no need to `read` it.
2. The filename (if any) is left in the positional argument after command line processing is done.
3. Don't process the file when you're not yet done with processing the command line flags.
4. The option string to `getopts` is backwards.

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Process command line.
#   Store r-flag's argument in ch,
#   Exit on invalid flags.
while getopts 'r:' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        r) ch="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) echo 'Error' >&2
           exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

# Make sure we got r-flag.
if [[ -z "$ch" ]]; then
    echo 'Missing -r flag' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Shift positional parameters so that first non-flag argument
# is left in $1.
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

if [[ -f "$1" ]] || [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    # $1 is a (regular) file, or unset.
    # Use file for input, or stdin if unset.
    cat "${1:--}" | tr -d "$ch"
else
    # $1 is set, but not a filename, pass it as string to tr.
    tr -d "$ch" <<<"$1"
fi
```

This would be used as

```
$ ./script -r 'a-z' file
```

(deletes all lowercase characters in `file`)

```
$ ./script -r 'a-z' "Hello World!"
```

(deletes all lowercase characters in the given string, *unless it happens to be a filename*)

```
$ ./script -r 'a-z'
```

(deletes all lowercase character in the standard input stream)

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Makes heaps of sense that way.